# В пагинации активная страница по центру

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pagination

Как можно в пагинации сделать актуальную страницу по центру? Допустим, если выбрана 4 страница, то она была бы по центру, а 1-3 рядом слева, а 5-7 рядом справа.
Код:

```html
<div>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <a class="page">2</a>
  <a class="page">3</a>
  <a class="actual_page">4</a>
  <a class="page">5</a>
  <a class="page">6</a>
  <a class="page">7</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, без js тут не обойтись

Comment: @Cheg, как это можно с JS?

Comment: jquery подойдет?

Comment: @Cheg, не принципиально :)

Comment: А ширина ссылок у всех одинаковая?

Comment: @Cheg,  порядковые числа

Comment: Я имею ввиду ширина самих ссылок `a`

Comment: @Cheg, да, одинаковая. Как в примере кода, только без ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. CSS никакого топикстартер не предоставил, на основе этого можно сделать как-то так:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  var pages = $(this).find('.page'), // все ссылки
    pagesLength = pages.length, // кол-во страниц
    active = $(this).find('.actual_page').index() + 1, // номер активной страницы
    pageWidth = pages.outerWidth(), // ширина ссылки

    pagesRight = pagesLength - active, // кол-во страниц справа от активной
    pagesLeft = pagesLength - pagesRight - 1, // кол-во страниц слева от активной
    pagesDiff = (pagesLeft - pagesRight); // разница между кол-вами страниц слева и справа

  if (pagesDiff < 0) { // если слева меньше
    $(this).css({
      'padding-right': '0px',
      'padding-left': pagesDiff * -1 * pageWidth + 'px'
    });
  } else if (pagesDiff > 0) { // если справа меньше
    $(this).css({
      'padding-left': '0px',
      'padding-right': pagesDiff * pageWidth + 'px'
    });
  } else if (pagesDiff == 0) { // если равно
    $(this).css({
      'padding-left': '0px',
      'padding-right': '0px'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 220%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -60%;
  z-index: -1;
}

a {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.actual_page {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="page actual_page">1</a>
  <a class="page">2</a>
  <a class="page">3</a>
  <a class="page">4</a>
  <a class="page">5</a>
  <a class="page">6</a>
  <a class="page">7</a>
</div><br />
<div>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <a class="page actual_page">2</a>
  <a class="page">3</a>
  <a class="page">4</a>
  <a class="page">5</a>
  <a class="page">6</a>
  <a class="page">7</a>
</div><br />
<div>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <a class="page">2</a>
  <a class="page actual_page">3</a>
  <a class="page">4</a>
  <a class="page">5</a>
  <a class="page">6</a>
  <a class="page">7</a>
</div><br />
<div>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <a class="page">2</a>
  <a class="page">3</a>
  <a class="page actual_page">4</a>
  <a class="page">5</a>
  <a class="page">6</a>
  <a class="page">7</a>
</div><br />
<div>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <a class="page">2</a>
  <a class="page">3</a>
  <a class="page">4</a>
  <a class="page actual_page">5</a>
  <a class="page">6</a>
  <a class="page">7</a>
</div><br />
<div>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <a class="page">2</a>
  <a class="page">3</a>
  <a class="page">4</a>
  <a class="page">5</a>
  <a class="page actual_page">6</a>
  <a class="page">7</a>
</div><br />
<div>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <a class="page">2</a>
  <a class="page">3</a>
  <a class="page">4</a>
  <a class="page">5</a>
  <a class="page">6</a>
  <a class="page actual_page">7</a>
</div><br />
```

Чтобы данный пример работал корректно, **ВАЖНО**, чтобы:

- ширина ссылок пагинатора должна быть одинаковой;
- между ссылками не должно быть никакого расстояния.